# Cx_Freeze with FastF1

Tags: python, streamlit, cx-freeze

i cannot import the library `fastf1` when I create an executable file with `cx_Freeze`. This lib is in the built folder, but for some reason when I use `cx_Freeze` it's not find this lib.

Someone can help me?

My files to create the executable with `Cx_Freeze`:

setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [Executable("run.py", base="Win32GUI", icon="icon.ico")]

setup(
    name="FTS F1",
    version="1.0",
    description="Software to analyze F1 data.",
    executables=executables,
)
```

run.py:

```
import streamlit as st
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.run("python -m streamlit run main.py")
```

And `main.py` is my project.

Comment: I never used `Cx_Freeze` but maybe it has the same problem as `pyinstaller` - it may need to add (manually) this library to some settings to correctly add it to executable.